# Cleaning up images in matlab

Tags: matlab

How would you use Matlab to do the following? I've got fuzzy square images about the same size and then inside the fuzzy square there's smaller fuzzy squares, and I want to clean up the larger squares - not the smaller ones - so that they are no longer blurred. It looks like I'd have to make some type of morphological mask, but I'm not sure how in this case.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show an example of your image.

Comment: Also, please tell us what you know. Do you have a mask for the location of the squares?

Answer (score 1):

If you know where the large fuzzy squares pixels are, (based on pixel values) you can save their location(s). Turn all other pixels to 0 or 1 except at these locations. Use the 'find' function (location - find(image==value) to find the location.

If the values of the large fuzzy square are a range [ value1 value2], then u could use a for loop with if statement.

```
for a =1:m
  for b= 1:n % image is mxn matrix
     if image(a,b)<=value1 && image(a,b) >=value2
        image(a,b) = 0;
     end
  end
end
```

Sounds simple enough unless I misunderstood your question

Comment: If the OP _had_ to use this logic, a better implementation would be:
image( image<=value1 & image>=value2 ) = 0